# WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain:6001/app/websocketkey?protocol=7' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, websocket, pusher

I'm facing an issue : WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain:6001/app/websocketkey?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.4.0&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

While this app is properly working on localhost but not on Live server. SSL activated

I'm already using this setting in local machine it's perfectly fine but not on live server.

If anyone face this issue then share your thoughts on it ?
Thanks

```
This is my broadcasting.php


pusher' => [
             'driver' => 'pusher',
             'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
             'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
             'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
             'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'useTLS' => true,
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ],
             ],
           ],




and my websockets.php
local_cert' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/cert.pem',
local_pk' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem',

and my .env
PUSHER_APP_ID=testapp
PUSHER_APP_KEY=websocketkey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=somethingsecret
```

Comment: please change  your 'host' => '127.0.0.1' to 'host' => 'your domain name',